# Zip over dictionary with two iterators in Python3x

Tags: python-3.x, zip, ordereddictionary

I am trying to put together a calendar maker program so that I can better understand python dictionaries.

The stage of the development of my mini program is to express the following pseudo-code in python:

```
for i in number_of_dictionary_keys, j in range(j, 30):
    change the value of number @ that key to j
```

So I have an Ordereddict object:

```
weekdays = { 'Mon': 0, 'Tue': 0, 'Wed': 0, 'Thu': 0, 'Fri': 0, 'Sat': 0, 'Sun': 0 }
```

and, say j = 4, I want to change the values of the dict like this:

weekdays = { 'Mon': 5, 'Tue': 6, 'Wed': 7, 'Thu': 8, 'Fri': 9, 'Sat': 10, 'Sun': 11 }

I want to do this in the most pythonic way, so something like this:

```
for i, j zip(key in enumerate(weekdays_1, 1), range(j, 30)):
        weekdays[key] = j
```

but I can't get that to work. Is it possible to use zip in this way? What are the alternatives?

Comment: This looks interesting but I'm not sure how your code is supposed to create a calendar. Could you explain it a bit more detailed?  BTW, if you need to cycle through the weekdays, [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) could be helpful.

Comment: Well I didn't specify that coz I wanted to solve that problem myself - and I did btw! That is useful tho and I'll bear it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keys()` to iterate over all the keys in a `dict` / `OrderedDict`. Here is an example with a regular `dict` :

```
j = 4
weekdays = { 'Mon': 0, 'Tue': 0, 'Wed': 0, 'Thu': 0, 'Fri': 0, 'Sat': 0, 'Sun': 0 }
for key, j in zip(weekdays.keys(), range(j, 30)):
    weekdays[key] = j + 1

print(weekdays)
#{'Mon': 5, 'Tue': 6, 'Wed': 7, 'Thu': 8, 'Fri': 9, 'Sat': 10, 'Sun': 11}
```